# Hypotenuse of right angled triangle inscribed in circle must be a diameter

Tags: vectors

[image]

Was trying to proof the property using vectors where if you have a right angled triangle inscribed in a circle as in the drawing below, then $AB$ must form a diameter or equivalently $|AB|^2=4r^2$. However, I seem to have made a mistake somewhere since it's possible for $\vec{c}\cdot (\vec{b}-\vec{a})$ to be non-zero. Would be very helpful if anyone could help me check.

Comment: I think it should be $\vec{c}\cdot (\vec{b}+\vec{a})=0$

Comment: ah okay i see it now, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some errors with signs. When you expand $(\vec c-\vec a)\cdot(\vec c-\vec b)$ to reach an expression for $-2\vec a \cdot \vec b$, we should have
$$
\begin{align}
(\vec c-\vec a)\cdot(\vec c-\vec b)=0
&\implies  \vec c\cdot \vec c-\vec a\cdot \vec c-\vec b\cdot \vec c+\vec a\cdot \vec b=0 \\ 
&\implies  \lVert c\rVert^2=\vec a\cdot \vec c+\vec b\cdot \vec c-\vec a\cdot \vec b \\
&\implies  2\vec a\cdot \vec b=2\vec a\cdot \vec c+2\vec b\cdot \vec c-2\lVert c\rVert^2\\
&\implies  2\vec a\cdot \vec b=2\vec c\cdot (\vec a + \vec b)-2\lVert c\rVert^2\\
&\implies  -2\vec a\cdot \vec b=2\lVert c\rVert^2-2\vec c\cdot (\vec a + \vec b).
\end{align}
$$
Specifically, you have $(\vec a - \vec b)$ in the last step instead of $(\vec a + \vec b)$. The sign correction leads you to
$$
\lVert\vec{AB}\rVert^2=4r^2-2\vec c\cdot (\vec a + \vec b)=4r^2-2\vec c\cdot \vec0=4r^2
$$
which completes your proof.

Comment: ah okay, thank you very much, i see it now